# Flutter: Positioning images in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I just started learning flutter of some tutorials, but I have one thing i want to archive. I have problem with positioning images in my code. This is the issue.

[image: Image under logo].

If someone can recode this because I'm trying 2 days and can't understand how it works.

Solution I'm trying to find is to position image under logo into top right corner without moving logo and textbars

Draft of my wanting:

[image: What i want to do]

My codes:

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kafe/screens/login_screen.dart';
 
 
 
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Email and Password Login',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.brown,
      ),
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

**login_screen.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}
 
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
 // form key
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 
 // Editing Controller
final TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController locationController = new TextEditingController();
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    //Name field
    final emailField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: emailController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    //validator: {} {},
    onSaved: (value)
    {
        emailController.text = value!;
 
    },
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
      hintText: "Вашето име",
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
    ),
    );
 
    //password field
    final passwordField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: passwordController,
    //validator: {} {},
    onSaved: (value)
    {
        passwordController.text = value!;
 
    },
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.call_end_outlined),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
      hintText: "Вашиот телефонски број",
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
    ),
    );
 
    //Location field
    final locationField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: locationController,
 
    //validator: {} {},
    onSaved: (value)
    {
        locationController.text = value!;
 
    },
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.add_location_alt_outlined),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
      hintText: "Вашата локација",
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
 
      ),
    )),
 
    // button
 
   loginButton = Material(
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
    color: Colors.redAccent,
    child: MaterialButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text(
        "Логирање", 
      textAlign: TextAlign.center, 
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
      color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
       ),
      ),
    ),
  );        
 
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(35.0),
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget> [
 
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 130,
 
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child: Image.asset("assets/top.png",
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        ),
                        ),
                    ),
 
 
 
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 250,
 
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/logo.png",
 
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      )
                    ),
 
 
 
 
 
                    emailField,
                    SizedBox(height: 30),
 
                    passwordField,
                    SizedBox(height: 30),
 
                    locationField,
                    SizedBox(height: 30),
                    loginButton,
                    SizedBox(height: 30),
                  ],
                ),
 
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ) ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your widget tree, the `logo.png` is placed after `top.png` image , It's an order issue, place `logo` as 1st child on `Column`

```dart
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 250,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/logo.png",
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 130,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/top.png",
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      ),
                    ),
```

But next image describe you like to position the image. For this, wrap `SizedBox` with `Align` widget.

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 130,
```

Also, I would prefer `Stack` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can try postioned or align and go play with it. but you need them to wrap by **stack**

```
          Stack(
            color: Colors.white,
            child:  Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget> [
 
                    Positioned(
                      left:0,top:0
                      child: SizedBox(
                      width: 130,
 
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child: Image.asset("assets/top.png",
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        ),
                        ),
                            ),
                              ),
              Align(
               alignment: Alingment.center,
               child: Column(
                children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 250,
 
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/logo.png",
 
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      )
                    ),
 
 
 
 
 
                    emailField,
                    SizedBox(height: 30),
 
                    passwordField,
                    SizedBox(height: 30),
 
                    locationField,
                    SizedBox(height: 30),
                    loginButton,
                    SizedBox(height: 30),
                  ]
               )
                 ),
 
 
 
                    
                  ],
                ),
 
              ),
            ),
          ),
```